# Exclude Specific Crashes in CrashAnaytics

Tags: java, android, exception, crash-reports, crashlytics

**What I Have**

I have CrashAnaytics setup for my app and it works flawlessly so far. I also have disabled it for my debug build and is only enabled for my release builds.

```
Crashlytics crashlyticsKit = new Crashlytics.Builder()
                .core(new CrashlyticsCore.Builder().disabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG).build())
                .build();
        Fabric.with(this, crashlyticsKit);
```

**What I Want**

In my app, I sometimes deliberately need to throw an exception and crash the app. You can consider it as a feature where the user can force close or crash the app if they want to.

```
throw new FakeCrashException();
```

Now, the problem is that I am getting plenty of these crashes reported in CrashAnalytics as well. I know that these are not real crashes and there is no point in logging them in CrashAnalytics.

Is there a way I can exclude this specific exception from being reported by CrashAnalytics?

Answer (score 0):

Mike from Fabric here.

Have you thought about logging these as Caught Exceptions instead of FakeCrashes?

Using: `Crashlytics.logException(e);` may accomplish what you're looking for as this would not be considered crashes and wouldn't affect your crash-free statistics. More information [within the documentation.](https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/caught-exceptions.html)

Comment: These are not caught exceptions. They are uncaught and will effectively crash the application. That's the purpose of these fake crashes. Is there a way to ignore them?

Comment: Ah, I see - I misread the original post. You can lock the issue so that you're not notified, but the statistics would still be affected by the crashes coming in.

Comment: Okay. Is there any work-around to solve this corner case?

Comment: Not without logging the crash :( I haven't heard of too many app users needing to crash an app though.

Comment: Yes, this is a very specific use-case. Thought to seek some help on it.